# Adding a multiple of one row to a multiple of another row

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Which of the following are elementary row operation?

> (A) Multiplying row 2 by any real number a

> (B) Interchange row 1 and row 2

> (C) Add 2 times of row 1 to 3 times of row 2

My answer is only (B), because (C) is a combination of 2 elementary row operation, but I am unsure as (C) technically doesn't change the solution set of the system just like any other elementary row operation.

**Should (C) be included in the answer?**

Thank you.

Comment: C) is a combination of two row operations, so not elementary (by my textbooks defn). It is fine to do though.

Comment: For (A), the real number $a$ that one multiplies row 2 by must be **nonzero**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for (C), you are adding a multiple of one row to a $\textit{multiple}$ of another row. What this means is that instead of adding a multiple of row 1 to just row 2, what you are given is that row 2 has already been multiplied by a constant number that is 3, and then is added by 2$\times$row 1. This means that two-row operations are occurring at once which can not be considered as an elementary row operation. Moreover, (A) is indecisive because you are told to multiply row 2 by any real number $a$ which could be zero and violate the elementary row operation.